# Android drawCircle's are not always 360 degrees

Tags: android, graphics

When I call drawCircle (ex. `canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);`) and I use Paint Style `STROKE` to initialize the parameter `mPaint`, the result doesn't quite make a full 360 degrees (2*PI radian) circle in all cases.  Sometimes you get a full circle (as I would expect) and sometimes only an arc.

Does someone have an idea what would cause this to happen ?

I don't know what cases work and which don't (yet).  I've noticed the ones that don't work seem to be the larger circles I'm drawing (>100.0 radius).  Could be size related.  I am using floating point for x, y and r.  I could try rounding to the nearest int when in the drawing code.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Confirm it is repeatable and submit a bug report.
http://source.android.com/report-bugs
(I did a quick search on the bugs for drawcircle and none are present at the moment)

Comment: What cases don't draw a full circle? One of my apps draws tons of circles that constantly change in size from r=1 to r=250 and are centered all over the screen, i've never had this issue. I do clamp my x,y,r to integer values

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything else to the canvas before the drawCircle? This could happen if, for example you are scaling the canvas or transforming it before you draw the circle.

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not scaling the canvas.  How would one go about scaling a canvas?